# Set order ID back to 000000001

Tags: magento2, php, database, orders, magento2.2.3

To remove the orders from the database, I use the following queries:

```
$connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
$connection->rawQuery('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;');
$connection->rawQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;');

$connection->rawQuery('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
```

This successfully deletes all orders from the DB.

My question is:

*How to reset the order ID back to 000000001 so the first new order will start with that id?*

I've been searching for this, but most answers require you to do this by hand, but I want to achieve this by running a query from a PHP file.

-- EDIT --
Running the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM `sequence_order_1`
```

Directly in phpmyadmin returns:

[image]

Also runnning:

```
ALTER TABLE `sequence_order_1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 000000001;
```

in phpmyadmin does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your `sequence_order_1` table in database.

> sequence_order_1 is for 1st store view.

If you change your series id, you can use a prefix,

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700000001;
```

Take note that the prefix `7` has been added. This number has to be higher than the previous prefix. So if your first sequence was like `000000001`, then new sequence order has to be at least `100000001`.

Magento default provides 9 digits for Id. and execute it in the database.

This will help you more.

Comment: When running `$connection->rawQuery('ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 000000001;');`, new created orders still continue to use the old sequence order..

Comment: How many stores available on your site?

Comment: I have one store but single store mode is not enabled. Check my updated question

Comment: Check this table `sequence_order_1` in database. Value is updated or not.

Comment: If you mean that if I start a new order, and if that table will be updated after, than yes. `sequence_order_1 ` gets updated with a new value. Is it not possible to truncate this table?

Comment: Its possible. try that case and check it.

Comment: Won't work. `TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1` won't affect the table at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75725/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-bramulous).

Comment: I truncate table and work for me(For new reader only).